# Get column name if value exists in a cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I got following excel sheet:

[image: Excel sheet]

Iterating through each of the rows I need to extract column name wherever 'x' value occurs. How could I do that? There's no option to "get column name" basing on the cell.

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel("/Users/farmaceut/Sites/journals_database/journals.xlsx", header=[2, 3])
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
for col in df.columns[8:]:
...Domain.objects.update_or_create(domain_name=col[0])
for index, col in df.iterrows():
......journal = Journal.objects.update_or_create(title=col[1], abbreviation=col[4], impact_factor=0,ministerial_points=col[7])
for cell in col[8:]:
...if cell == 'x':
......????
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? Please provide a sample input that's text, not picture. I can't copy a picture meaningfully. Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: You almost have enough information for an adequate question, but you need to put a little more work into it.

Comment: All I need is to get the title of the column where 'x' appears, but for each row separately

Comment: You need to post an mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I have no idea what you want to see, and judging by your question, I'm not convinced you do either.

Comment: I guess the query is to get the column name where a particular value (string or numeric) matches based on the details provided.

Comment: Here's a [fragment](https://easyupload.io/g3x4z9) of my spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Please view the below Code to find indices and the columns where character `a` is present. Change `a` with the character you want to find and you'll get the indices as well as the column where the character is present.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":['fdsf','dfsa'],"B":[1,2]})
indices=[]
columns=[]
for column in df.columns:
    values=list(df[df[column].astype(str).str.contains('a')].index)
    if(len(values)>0):
        indices.append(values)
        columns.append(column)
```

In this case, the output will be

```
columns=['A'] # Column where 'a' is found
indices=[[1]] # Index where 'a' is found
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I need to get the column name wherever 'x' is found, and for each row separately. This cannot be done at once, because i won't be able to set my model (Journal) values as I did with iterrows

Comment: The rows where 'x' is found would be in the 'indices' ( list of lists) where each individual list corresponds to the rows where 'x' is present and the corresponding column is present in the 'columns' list. In this example, it means that at row 1, column 'A' the character 'a' is present.

Comment: Okey, though where I should implement this code? After `for index, col in df.iterrows()`? Or  after `for cell in col[8:]:` ?

Comment: As per your code, it seems that you are finding 'x' at the end (after the iterrows()), so this code goes at the end